# Connect React Native Program to MySQL Database

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an app built with React Native and I'm wondering if there's a way to directly connect it to a remote MySQL database.
I've been looking for solutions online but most of the codes I found are written in PHP or require the use of Express.
However, I don't have access to the remote server to run PHP or run Express. Is it possible to establish a direct connection between my React Native app and the remote MySQL database? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to establish a direct connection between your React Native app and a remote MySQL database. However, it is not recommended to connect to the database directly from the client-side app due to security concerns. It's generally a best practice to have a server-side API that acts as an intermediary between your app and the database.

But if you don't mind the risk you can try this library [Node MySQL 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)
and read more about the issue with this approach [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/uj1mk3/connecting_to_mysql_database_from_react_native/)